# How to create new column based on arithmetic operation after doing GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a syntax question. I was trying an exercise out of the book "Practical SQL" by Anthony DeBarros. I did the exercise, which involved creating two new columns that created percent changes based on four columns from two different data sets. The query below runs great:

```
SELECT pls14.stabr AS us_state, 
       sum(pls14.gpterms) AS terminals_2014,
       sum(pls09.gpterms) AS terminals_2009,
       round( (CAST(sum(pls14.gpterms) AS decimal(10,1)) - sum(pls09.gpterms)) /
                    sum(pls09.gpterms) * 100, 2 ) AS terminal_pct_change,
        sum(pls14.pitusr) AS term_uses_2014,
       sum(pls09.pitusr) AS term_uses_2009,
       round( (CAST(sum(pls14.pitusr) AS decimal(10,1)) - sum(pls09.pitusr)) /
                    sum(pls09.pitusr) * 100, 2 ) AS term_uses_pct_change
FROM pls_fy2014_pupld14a pls14 JOIN pls_fy2009_pupld09a pls09
ON pls14.fscskey = pls09.fscskey
WHERE pls14.gpterms >= 0 AND pls09.gpterms >= 0
GROUP BY pls14.stabr
ORDER BY terminal_pct_change DESC;
```

It results in the following table:

```
us_state terminals_2014 terminals_2009 terminal_pct_change term_uses_2014 term_uses_2009 term_uses_pct_change
"GU"    547      59     827.12  39842   19564   103.65
"DC"    1000    594     68.35   1050623 140251  649.10
"AK"    994     618     60.84   771075  1061498 -27.36
"DE"    772     487     58.52   622515  451689  37.82
"ID"    1792    1151    55.69   1878131 1986141 -5.44
"CO"    6407    4172    53.57   7395748 7672580 -3.61
```

I was wanting to do add a column that would show me the simple difference between the `terminal_pct_change` and `term_use_pct_change` columns. I tried a lot of things and nothing has worked. I'm not sure where the insert the following line.

```
terminal_pct_change - term_uses_pct_change AS kept_up
```

I would love ideas to a) get this working, but more importantly b) to understand how the solution works.

Thanks!

Comment: Repeat the expressions, use a subquery, or use a CTE.

Comment: It is impossible to reuse column-aliases from the ```SELECT``` clause in the same ```SELECT``` clause. You can refer to the alias, if you wrap another select around your statement (your statement becomes a sub-select, that you can access in this place just like a table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select x.us_state,x.terminals_2014,x.terminals_2009,(x.terminal_pct_change - x.term_uses_pct_change) AS kept_up,term_uses_2014,term_uses_2009 from (
SELECT pls14.stabr AS us_state, 
       sum(pls14.gpterms) AS terminals_2014,
       sum(pls09.gpterms) AS terminals_2009,
       round( (CAST(sum(pls14.gpterms) AS decimal(10,1)) - sum(pls09.gpterms)) /
                    sum(pls09.gpterms) * 100, 2 ) AS terminal_pct_change,
        sum(pls14.pitusr) AS term_uses_2014,
       sum(pls09.pitusr) AS term_uses_2009,
       round( (CAST(sum(pls14.pitusr) AS decimal(10,1)) - sum(pls09.pitusr)) /
                    sum(pls09.pitusr) * 100, 2 ) AS term_uses_pct_change
FROM pls_fy2014_pupld14a pls14 JOIN pls_fy2009_pupld09a pls09
ON pls14.fscskey = pls09.fscskey
WHERE pls14.gpterms >= 0 AND pls09.gpterms >= 0
GROUP BY pls14.stabr
ORDER BY terminal_pct_change DESC)x ;
```